# Python: How to iterate over specific columns in rows in text file

Tags: python, loops

I would like to iterate a script along columns in a text file but ignoring the first 5 columns.

Currently my script runs through a text file row by row assessing the values in column 6. I would like it to then run through all the rows assessing column 6, then column 7, then column 8 etc
I DO NOT want to assess each column for every row as the script reads through the file, but to run through the entire file assessing column n and then repeat for column n + 1

Currently I have the simple:

```
for line in Input:
    line = line.rstrip() 
    fields = line.split("\t")
    for col in row:
```

but I'd like to specify that it ignores the first 5 columns, as these are not targets (but are still needed as information in the file).

I guess something like for col in row for range 6:20 might work, but I am a python beginner and don't know the correct way to express this in python. Please let me know how I can clarify the question if it is too confusing.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best,

Rubal

Comment: you could use `csv` module and `cols = row[5:]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a list `row`, then `row[a:b]` is the range of elements starting with element number `a` and up to but not including element number `b`.

For example:

```
row = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon']

print row[2:4]
```

The output of this would be

```
['gamma', 'delta']
```

And so in a loop you can write:

```
for col in row[6:20]:
    foo()
```

Alternatively, loop to the end of the list with

```
for col in row[6:]:
    foo()
```

Comment: +1: More useful than my answer, given the OP's level of experience

Comment: +1 for both, @marshall for brevity and giving exactly the answer I would give, and Eliot for the solid explanation.

Comment: thanks, that should solve it Eliot Ball. What is the foo() for?

Comment: The `foo()` means 'put your own code here'. Foo is commonly used as a placeholder without meaning.

Answer (score 4):

```
for line in Input:
    line = line.rstrip() 
    fields = line.split("\t")
    for col in fields[5:]:
        # process
```

Answer (score 2):

Without copying

```
for line in Input:
    line = line.rstrip() 
    fields = line.split("\t")
    for index in range(5, len(fields)):
        #do_smth with fields[index]
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, all these comments are useful. I have a much improved understanding of how to create these iterating structures now!